# How to import a Public Key into RSA For decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

This may seem like a stupid question but I have been searching for the last hour and a half. I have a message that is encrypted with a PRIVATE KEY of a RSA key pair. I have the PUBLIC KEY that I need to use to decrypt the message. I've been searching for a way to import the public key into a RSACryptoProvider but can't seem to find a way. I simply have a BigInteger object as the modulus and the exponent (constitutes a public key). I can't seem to find a way to get it to decrypt anything. I have tried

```
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportParameters(new System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters { Exponent = BitConverter.GetBytes(12345), Modulus = BigInteger.Parse("HEX of public key", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToByteArray() });
_session.EncryptionKey = rsa.Decrypt(_session.EncryptionKey, false);
```

All this does is throws up a CryptographicException saying there is no key set. Is there something I need to flag to let it know I want to decrypt using a public key?

Comment: Are you sure that message was encrypted with PRIVATE key? If you just use the private key handle for encryption, high-level RSA implementations will use corresponding public key for this operation.

Comment: Yes. The use of the private key for encryption is to make it that only the party with the private key can generate keys for the client as the public key is hardcoded in the client. Its a sort of verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon Pavel's answer we decided it would be best to do the math ourselves. We ended up with

```
var encryptionKey = new BigInteger(_session.EncryptionKey);
var result = encryptionKey.modPow(12345, BigInteger.Parse("HEX of public key", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToByteArray());
_session.EncryptionKey = result.ToByteArray();
```

(There is some unpadding in the middle but as that was no relevant to the question, I omitted it)

Thanks for all the answers :)

Answer (score 2):

> All this does is throws up a CryptographicException saying there is no key set. Is there something I need to flag to let it know I want to decrypt using a public key?

No. High- and middle-level cryptographic libraries don't support such abnormal operations as private key encryption and public key decryption. You need to implement RSA using mathematical primitives, if you want them.

Maybe, you need a digital signature mechanism instead?

Answer (score 1):

Most people don't decrypt with a public key, because the "decrypt" defined with a public key is merely a component of verifying a signature with a public key. Hence RSACryptoServiceProvider just does VerifyHash, and Encrypt with public keys.

Your sample code inclusion of `_session.EncryptionKey` suggests that you are trying to implement a [hybrid cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). If this cryptosystem you are implementing uses **public** keys to decrypt then you have NO secrecy.

I've written a C# implementation of google's highlevel encryption framework keyczar, and it includes an easy to use [hybrid crypto](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-dotnet/wiki/Session-Encryption).

Comment: The point of RSA is to confirm the identity of the person who generated the EncryptionKey. We have been suffering man-in-the-middle attacks and the whole point of using Private to encrypt is to make sure that no other third party can generate and encrypt their own key as the public key is hardcoded in the client.

Comment: @jduncantor If EncryptionKey is a symmetric key, a man in the middle attack is not prevented by what you are doing.

Comment: How so? I'm using Diffie-Hellman as a key exchange method. The server's key which he is sending alice and has been generated from a random secret is encrypted with the servers private key and sent to the client. The client then decrypts it with the public key and does the normal diffie-hellman equations to get the shared secret. Mallet (man in the middle) cannot generate a key to send to Alice because he cannot encrypt it because he doesn't know the private key, so when Alice tries to decrypt it with the public key, incorrect key is returned.

Comment: @jduncanator  
It didn't look like you were double encrypting the key, but if you have been been suffering man in the middle attacks, just protecting the key exchange probably isn't enough, you are only making it tougher, the symmetric ciphertext is really what needs the authenticity.

Comment: @jduncanator if you don't authenticate your ciphertexts, they can be forged, which leaves you open to several attack vectors. And since your broken protocol was already attacked, you really should fix it right or even better switch to a well known protocol/implementation.

Comment: To be honest, I'm working with someone elses code. It's a client application for a horrible documented server and we can't really have access to the servers source. We can only work with what we are given. However I will pass on the information to the developers (not that they will do anything :P)